# Structure Map violates the constraint of type parameter 'CONCRETETYPE'

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have a web application developed in ASP.NET 2010. I have used the Dependency Injection with StructureMap in ASP.NET MVC.  I'm trying to get started with Structure Map. I'm using

I've built a simple boot strapper, but when I run the website I get the following error:

> StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions.CreatePluginFamilyExpression`1[System.Web.Mvc.IActionInvoker].Use:
>   type argument
>   'TestWebsite.Web.Controllers.Factories.InjectingActionInvoker'
>   violates the constraint of type parameter 'CONCRETETYPE'.

**Code Block:**

```
 public static void ConfigureStructureMap()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            //registry per assembly recommended
            x.AddRegistry<WebRegistry>();
            x.AddRegistry<ServiceRegistry>();
            x.AddRegistry<SHARE.Data.DataRegistry>();
        });

        //if a class needs configuring on load then this is done here. Inherit from IStartUpTask
        ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IStartUpTask>()
            .Where(x => x.IsEnabled).ToList()
            .ForEach(t => t.Configure());

        //This checks all is well.  Not ideal to do in application_start though cause of calls to request object....
        //ObjectFactory.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }


  public class WebRegistry : Registry
    {
        public WebRegistry()
        {
         For<IFormsAuthentication>    ().Use<FormsAuthenticationService>();
         For<IAuthentication>().Use<BasicMembership>();
                     Scan(x =>
            {
                x.AssemblyContainingType<IStartUpTask>();
                x.AddAllTypesOf<IStartUpTask>();
                x.WithDefaultConventions();
            });

            For<IActionInvoker>().Use<InjectingActionInvoker>();
            SetAllProperties(c =>
            {
                c.OfType<IActionInvoker>();
                c.WithAnyTypeFromNamespaceContainingType<UserService>(); //our services
                c.WithAnyTypeFromNamespaceContainingType<AdminCookies>(); //cookie services
            });

        }
```

Could anyone please suggest on this issue. how it could be resolved? I am really getting troubled with it and need to resolve it asap. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Deepak

Comment: It would help if you post some code so we can see what you are trying.

Comment: Thanks tucaz, I have added some code block, Please have a look

Comment: Its a little bit hard to infer the problem without knowing what class does what. If you could post a smaller repro, one that I could actually copy and paste to see the error.

Comment: Sorry, But I am not able to provide the code due to company policy. This code is working on another machine but giving me the error. I think I am missing any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following changes to run:

1. Remove the reference of MVC 3.0 DLL from website
2. Add the reference of MVC 2.0 DLL in  website
3. Run the project and its working fine